# PHP - Append item to array but without altering original (i.e. return new instance)?

Tags: php, arrays, append

```
// default email addresses
$this->defaultEmail = array('no-reply@blah.com' => 'blah');
$consultant = ( isset($_POST['consultant']) ) ? $_POST['consultant'] : "";

$addresses = ( empty($consultant) ) ? $this->defaultEmail : ?? ;
```

Can I just use `array_push($this->defaultEmail, $consultant);`

Will it alter the original or just the `$addresses` pointer?

Comment: Why don't you simply test it? (to be a bit constructive, [this](http://www.php.net/manual/language.references.whatdo.php) might be helpful)

Comment: Haha was just thinking that... My commits take a few minutes so thought I might get speedy response.

Comment: You can also test such simple principles via [codepad](http://codepad.org/) or [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/)

Answer (score 0):

So maybe I did not word my question correctly but after some messing around this is the way to do it (if anyone cares):

```
$addresses = $this->defaultEmail;
if( !empty($consultant) ) {
    array_push($addresses, $consultant);
}
```